# How to get user Date of birth and gender in google plus latest SDK version 2.1.0 in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-plus

I am using sign in with Google plus, I updated Google Plus SDK version with 2.1.0,follow with the instruction on,
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide
link, but I am not getting user's DOB and his/her gender in user info.

I am using this delegate method for get user detail,

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
    NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
    NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
    NSString *name = user.profile.name;
    NSString *email = user.profile.email;
}
```

If any one know how to get user's gender and DOB then Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may not be with your code. Birthday and gender info is not always visible. I have tested it using [Try It](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get#try-it).  I tested it with all of the different scopes

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login Know your basic profile
> info and list of people in your circles.
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me Know who you are on Google
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email View your email address
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile View basic
> information about your account

It doesn't appear to matter you get back the birthday in all of the scopes. But what does matter is that the Users Birthday must be set to `public` in the Account.  If its set to anything else, your circles, only you. its not listed.  This appears to be true even when you are trying to see your own information.  (Sending Me)